# Chrome-Extension : chrome.tabs.executeScript return value

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get back a value from a script executed from inside a chrome application but if the value is coming from a function in the script, I can't get it back.

Here is an example that explains my problem.

1. First something that works...

In popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, 
  {
    file: 'test.js',
  }, function(results) 
  {
    console.log(results)
  });
```

in test.js (simplified code)

```
 document.getElementById("anything").innerHTML
```

In this case, the console.log returns the expected value

2. Now where I'm struggling...

I keep the same popup.js code but I change test.js with:

```
function myfunction ()
{
do some stuff here
}

myfunction().then(function(results)
{
    console.log(results);
    results;
});
```

In that case the console.log returns the value I'm expecting but how can I make it accessible for popup.js ? I need to wait until myfunction is finally executed to make sure I get the right data but that prevents me from simply outputting the content like in my first example. There must be something simple but I'm no expert.

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: executeScript returns only the immediate result. Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: ok, I thought of doing this too but I did not figure how to send the message to the script (test.js in my case). If I send the message to a tab containing an external site, how do I create the logic to send something back? Thanks!